# cshtml / view without an action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can I serve a cshtml page as a view without writing an action method?

So, if I have a controller called Help and a view called Money.cshtml I want to access it as localhost/help/money without writing an action method?

Comment: What is your goal in not writing action methods?  Is this for the purpose of managing your URLs (i.e. having that exact URL `localhost/help/money`), or do you simply not want to have to write action methods in the controller?  It's easy enough to write an action method that does nothing but render the View with the same name.

Comment: I don't want to write action methods when all they do is do a return view.  I have quite a few pages that are static and I want them to appear to belong in the same place as my views.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like the following.
Define a route that maps to just one action e.g.:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Help_default", // Route name
    "help/{path}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "About", action = "Page" }
);
```

Then your help controller could look like the following. It basically just grabs the path from the URL and passes that as the model to the view.

```
public class HelpController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Page(string path)
    {
        return View("Page", path);
    }
}
```

Your Page view could then look like:

```
@model string

@{
    string viewPath = string.Format("~/Views/Help/{0}.cshtml", Model);
    ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(this.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext, viewPath, null);
    if (result.View != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial(viewPath)
    } else {
        // Define a not found view in the shared folder?
        @Html.Partial("NotFound")
    }
}
```

Which basically checks to see if a view exists with that path or not. It feels a bit dirty but I think it would work.